# How many ways can we arrange 3 boys and 3 girls in a circular table if all boys should sit beside one another?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is what I've done so far:

I treat the groups of 3 people as 1 since the constraint is that all the 3 boys should sit beside one another. Since it's a group of 3 boys, and this would mean that the girls would do the same. We can treat each group as 1, then this means we will have 2 groups left. I applied the technique for the circular permutation for each groups, Then each group will be having 3 factorial.

$$(2-1)! \times (3!)^2 = 36$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The answer depends what you count as the same arrangement.  For example, does shifting everyone along by 1 count as different?  You are still sitting next to the same two person.  Or even swiching clockwise and anticlockwise?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is emphasized that the table is circular, it is reasonable to presume that rotational changes are not deemed to produce a different arrangement.

Your answer of $(3!)^2$ is correct:

Without Loss of Generality, the Head of the table (i.e. the 12 O'clock position in the circular table with 6 chairs) will be occupied by the **middle** boy (whoever that turns out to be).

Given that, with the boys seated at positions 10,12,2 and the girls seated at positions 4,6,8, each of the two groups (3 boys and 3 girls) can be permuted in $3!$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that there are 36 possible permutations considering only who is next to whom and on which side. 6 permutations for the boys, 6 for the girls.

But if the chairs are numbered, the boy who sits to the right of a girl can be in six different chairs, so there are 216 possible seatings.